# How to get the full class name of a sub-class with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass

I need to get the full name of a subclass.

Example:

```
class Foo:
    class Bar:
        pass


x = Foo.Bar()
print(x.__class__.__name__)
```

Output: *Bar*
Expected: *Foo.Bar*

Comment: Just a nitpick, this would be an "inner" class, not a "sub" class. `Bar` doesn't inherit from `Foo`. I'm hesitant to alter your terminology though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`__qualname__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__), this is the fully qualified name of the [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__)

```
class Foo:
    class Bar:
        pass


x = Foo.Bar()
print(x.__class__.__qualname__)
#OUTPUT: Foo.Bar
```

The best way is to call it on the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), it alredy call `__class__` on instance:

```
class Foo:
    class Bar:
        pass


x = Foo.Bar()
print(type(x).__qualname__)
#OUTPUT: Foo.Bar
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much for such a clean answer.

Comment: Didn't even know there was dunder methods for it, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `type`.

```
class Foo:
    class Bar:
        pass


x = Foo.Bar()
print(type(x))
```

```
<class '__main__.Foo.Bar'>
```

Strip `__main__` or not, up to you.